# Responding Globally to a 401 in Polymer

Tags: http, authentication, polymer, polymer-1.0, http-status-code-401

Using Polymer 1.0, I am looking for the best approach to showing a login to a user when the app receives a 401 from the app services.

Using Angular I would be looking at using a httpInterceptor to do this, is there an equivalent in Polymer?

Here's an approach which explicitly routes errors from a service element (using iron-ajax)

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <values-service values="{{items}}" on-error="onError"></values-service>

    <h1>Items <span>{{items}}</span></h1>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
        <p>{{item}}</p>
    </template>
</template>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

and my app script

```
(function (document) {
    'use strict';

    var app = document.querySelector('#app');

    app.onError = function (e) {

        console.log('app.onError ' + e.detail.request.status);
    };

    app.addEventListener('error', app.onError);

})(document);
```

this works, but as the login is something I want to happen without having to wire up elements specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is catching the error on an outermost element as the events bubble up through the dom

```
<div on-error="onError">
    <values-service values="{{items}}"></values-service>
    <other-service></other-service>
    ...

</div>
```

and some script (as above)

```
app.onError = function (e) {

    console.log('app.onError ' + e.detail.request.status);
};
```

when any of the contained services, or any contained elements containing services fire an error, the handler will trigger - I do the relevant checks for a request and a 401 and show my login dialog

Comment: The only downside to this is that the 401 checks will have to be in every callback; lots of duplicated and possibly brittle code, when you have enough of these. You could use the same system if you wrap the value-service element in a new element, that looks for 401s and fires off events named to be 401 explicitly.

Comment: 401's are controlled by my api

Comment: This approach means there is no duplication, there is only one 401 handler at the root. So not as you describe

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I created a component that was used for all my Ajax requests. In that component, listened for 401s from the service calls, and called this.fire('401-found') when found.

Then in my other components, I listened for such an event - in my case, in the main document, popping up a dialog asking the user to log in again.

A slightly better approach would be to have the Ajax component take in parameters to say 'yes fire a 401 event' and 'do not give it the standard 401 event, name call it this' then in each component you could listen for such events and react accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's a good idea. Thing is I may be using ajax components that I didn't write :/

Comment: Why not embed those ajax components in ones of your own? I embedded the polymer ajax components and then looked at the response object for 401 responses. What components are you using for the service calls?

Comment: that's what values-service in my example is, but the point here is global 401 handling

Comment: Wrap the value-services in a new component, which passes the values and error values onto the user of the new component, and in the onError callback, look for 401s and fire events as described above?

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a PR to [iron-ajax](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax) (which was merged a few days ago) that adds an optional `bubbles` attribute to accomplish exactly this. When the `bubbles` attribute is present, iron-ajax's `request`, `response`, and `error` events bubble to `window`. This means you can have global event listeners on `window` and handle `401`s however you want without any more code duplication that adding `bubbles` to your iron-ajax calls.

What's more, because it's part of iron-ajax, it is officially supported by the Polymer team.

Here's [the official docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-bubbles).